# Problem with mysql connection to local MariaDB MySQL Linux server via localhost/127.0.0.1 in c# mono app

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I made a plugin to collect data from the players on my SCP:SL (game) server and saving it to MySQL database.

When connect to external databases, located outside my local VPS(like freemysqlhosting), it works perfectly.

My local VPS is running `10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6 MySQL Server` with the newest mono version.

The problem starts when I am trying to connect to my MariaDB Linux MySQL database locally (via localhost/127.0.0.1).
When it comes to connect to the database, I am getting two different errors:

- one for localhost(the app isn't crashing),
- one for 127.0.0.1(the app is crashing)

I am getting this error, when host is specified as "localhost"

```
Unhandled Exception:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00014] in <ac210d81537245bc838518cc8e845861>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0002c] in <ac210d81537245bc838518cc8e845861>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <ac210d81537245bc838518cc8e845861>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00019] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout) [0x00000] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x0001f] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x00021] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x00007] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00014] in <ac210d81537245bc838518cc8e845861>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0002c] in <ac210d81537245bc838518cc8e845861>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <ac210d81537245bc838518cc8e845861>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00019] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 <---

  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x00041] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x0000e] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x0004e] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection () [0x00006] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () [0x0008a] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () [0x0003f] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection () [0x0001c] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x0016d] in <ffa6b95770be4daf8d8ae25ca059b16a>:0 
  at DataCollector.RoundEventHandler.<OnWaitingForPlayers>g__CheckIfTableExists|3_0 () [0x000db] in <8dda65d2174e4f2a8af95550bb525546>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) [0x00014] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0002b] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0
```

The error, when I am specifying host as "127.0.0.1" looks like that (it is so long so i attach a pastebin of it)

https://pastebin.com/Xf1hn3in

This is the c# mysql connection code for my plugin, I am using MySQLConnector v 8.0.13 to connect to the database:

```
                MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connstr = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                DatabaseConnInfo.dbhost = _plugin.GetConfigString("dc_dbhost");
                DatabaseConnInfo.dbname = _plugin.GetConfigString("dc_dbname");
                DatabaseConnInfo.dbuser = _plugin.GetConfigString("dc_dbuser");
                DatabaseConnInfo.dbpass = _plugin.GetConfigString("dc_dbpass");
                DatabaseConnInfo.dbport = (uint)_plugin.GetConfigInt("dc_dbport");

                connstr.Server = DatabaseConnInfo.dbhost;
                connstr.Database = DatabaseConnInfo.dbname;
                connstr.UserID = DatabaseConnInfo.dbuser;
                connstr.Password = DatabaseConnInfo.dbpass;
                connstr.Port = DatabaseConnInfo.dbport;
                _plugin.Info(connstr.ToString());
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                string sql = "some sql statement";
                MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                conn.Close();
```

The expected result is to have a working connection to the local database, which is not working due to the errors.

Those errors are weird, because I can connect to the external databases with ease, the local connection seems to be a problem, and I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The exception from using `"localhost"` is `SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used`. The cause is that Connector/NET doesn't support IPv6: [bug 83649](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83649).

The normal workaround would be to use an IPv4 address, e.g., `"127.0.0.1"`. However, I'm not sure about the cause of the new exception you get when you try that. It may be that Connector/NET isn't fully compatible with Mono?

I suggest trying [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), an OSS alternative MySQL library for .NET, to see if it resolves both these issues. It [fixes a lot of other bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs) in Connector/NET, and should be a drop-in replacement.